# Sidekiq: How to filter and retry Dead jobs belonging to a queue?

Tags: sidekiq

We have a lot of dead jobs belonging to multiple queues.
I'm looking for a way to filter dead jobs belonging to a particular queue and retry/delete them.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [API](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API) or use Sidekiq Pro's [Web UI Filtering](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Pro-Web-UI#filtering) feature.

Comment: This answer would be more helpful with an example rather than links to documentation alone.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it from backend/console according to [documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#dead)

```
ds = Sidekiq::DeadSet.new
ds.each do |job|
  # do with *job* what you want (filter, delete, redo)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
ds = Sidekiq::DeadSet.new

ds.each do |job|
    if job.queue == 'queue_name'
        # See content of the job
        puts job.inspect

        # Requeue the job
        job.retry

        # Delete job
        job.delete
    end
end
```